# How can we re-use the deleted id from any MySQL-DB table?

Tags: php, mysql

How can we re-use the deleted id from any MySQL-DB table?

If I want to rollback the deleted ID , can we do it anyhow?

Comment: Why do you want to reuse ids?

Comment: So that i can reinsert the old data not affecting any other processes

Comment: just rollback a transaction then

Comment: oh no it' the same tracking system for the poor again

Comment: If you want to be able to "reinsert" the data, don't delete it. Add a "DELETED" column to your table and insert the date of deletion inside. When you want to recover it, you just have to NULL the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be possible by finding the lowest unused ID and forcing it, but it's terribly bad practice, mainly because of referential integrity: It could be, for example, that relationships from other tables point to a deleted record, which would not be recognizable as "deleted" any more if IDs were reused.

Bottom line: Don't do it. It's a really bad idea.

Related reading: [Using auto_increment in the mySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Re your update: Even if you have a legitimate reason to do this, I don't think there is an automatic way to re-use values in an `auto_increment` field. If at all, you would have to find the lowest unused value (maybe using a stored procedure or an external script) and force that as the ID (if that's even possible.).

Comment: @Pekka I have scenario like If I am testing my data by deleting the previous one but it didnt work for me, but now I have to reuse the old data with the same old ID then what?

Comment: @Parth I don't understand your situation, but if you have to reuse old IDs you most likely have a design flaw somewhere. Can you elaborate in your question?

Comment: @Pekka, I am tracking the INsert Update and delete queries in a table, I am doing good with insert and Update as i dont face any problem with ID there, But once the delete action is performed I lose the unique ID which might be used at many places, and reinserting the old data will give new ID not the same old ID, hence for this case I need Old ID so that I can replicate the query in other db with same old ID

Comment: Just watch his question history. I's the comprehensive explanation.

Comment: @Parth not entirely to be honest - if you delete a record, why are there relationships to the record still in existence? Anyway, as I said, it's really tough to do in mySQL alone. You'd have to cook something up in the scripting language of your choice I think.

Comment: There is a possible use case, in v5.6 of mysql onduplicate update can increment IDs if you also update say a date field. Increments eventually can escape the INT limit. Its an old bug...

Comment: "Don't do it." isn't a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do it.
Don't think of it as a number at all.
It is not a number. It's unique identifier. Think of this word - *unique*. No record should be identified with the same id.

Comment: @Col. U can name me as "THE DATA TRACKER" :)

Comment: Agreed. This is nothing like a fragmented drive where things are less efficient if they're spread out. As long as your id's datatype can handle the values, don't worry about it. If it can't handle the values, get a new datatype.

Comment: @Parth If your ID's are currently UNSIGNED INTs, and you're approaching 4,294,967,295 records, upgrade to UNSIGNED BIGINTs (until you have 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 records).

Comment: @Parth SERIAL becomes a useful alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE.

Comment: "Don't do it." isn't answering his question.

Answer (score 1):

1.

As per your explanation provided "@Pekka, I am tracking the INsert Update and delete query..." I assume you just some how want to put your old data back to the same ID.

In that case you may consider using a delete-flag column in your table.

If the delete-flag is set for some row, you shall consider program to consider it deleted. Further you may make it available by setting the delete-flat(false).

Similar way is to move whole row to some temporary table and you can bring it back when required with the same data and ID.

Prev. idea is better though.

2.

If this is not what you meant by your explanation; and you want to delete and still use all the values of ID(auto-generated); i have a few ideas you may implement:
- Create a table (IDSTORE) for storing Deleted IDs.
- Create a trigger activated on row delete which will note the ID and store it to the table.
- While inserting take minimum ID from IDSTORE and insert it with that value. If IDSTORE is empty you can pass NULL ID to generate Auto Incremented number.

Of course if you have references / relations (FK) implemented, you manually have to look after it, as your requirement is so.

Further Read:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/10897_2201621_3/Deleting-Duplicate-Rows-in-a-MySQL-Database.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here is the my case for mysql DB:

I had menu table and the menu id was being used in content table as a foreign key. But there was no direct relation between tables (bad table design, i know but the project was done by other developer and later my client approached me to handle it). So, one day my client realised that some of the contents are not showing up. I looked at the problem and found that one of the menu is deleted from menu table, but luckily the menu id exist in cotent table. I found the menu id from content table that was deleted and run the normal insert query for menu table with same menu id along with other fields. (Id is primary key) and it worked.

```
insert into tbl_menu(id, col1, col2, ...) values(12, val1, val2, ...)
```